# how convert image pathe from ~/Images/image.jpg to Images/image.jpg

Tags: asp.net

when i upload image into database my picture  take a this path ~/Images/image.jpg but i would convert to this   Images/image.jpg or how to convert   to   Images/image.jpg  with c# code an put in img tag like under ex:

```
 <img src="images/image.jpg"></img>
```

this is my upload code:

```
       if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
                    {
                      string fileExt =      

System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

            if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
            {

                string FileName =        Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

                picpath = FileName;
                //Save files to disk
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + FileName));


            }
            else
            {
                picpath = "Images/defalut.jpg";
            }


            }
```

this is my viewcode:

```
                <%



                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection thisConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
                    SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
                    thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from product";
                    thisConnection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string id =Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(0));
                        string title = reader.GetString(1);
                        string price = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(4));
                        string  image= reader.GetString(7);

                %>


                    <div class="prod_box">
                    <div class="center_prod_box">            
                        <div class="product_title"><a href="acer.aspx"><%  Response.Write(title);%></a></div>
                        <div class="product_img"><a href="acer.aspx"><img src="<%  Response.Write(image);%>" height="120px" width="120px" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></div>
                        <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce"></span> <span class="price"><%  Response.Write(price);%></span></div>                        
                    </div>
                <div class="prod_details_tab">
```

More

```
                    <%

                      }
                    thisConnection.Close();

                    %>
```

Comment: Server.MapPath change to full path: D:/MyFolder/MyWebsite/Images/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
var outputDir =Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

        var ImageName= Path.Combine(outputDir , "Images\\image.jpg");

        string ImageNew= new Uri(ImageName).LocalPath;

        var imgName= new LinkedResource(ImageNew)
```